# Python Dataframe: change values of a specified column of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe object df:

```
    A        B         C       
0  0.0      5.0       0.0        
1  0.0      6.0       0.0        
2  0.0      9.0       0.0        
3  0.0      0.0       0.0        
4  0.0      2.0       0.0        
5  0.0      5.0       0.0        
6  6.0      0.0       0.0        
7  0.0      0.0       0.0        
8  0.0      1.0       0.0
```

I want to change the values of column 'B':

If the value is smaller than 3, than the value should be replaced with 'False'.

Otherwise the value should be replaced with 'True'.

I tried:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: [False if y < 3 else True for y in x])
```

In this case I get the TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable.

When I use it for the whole Dataframe it works though:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: [False if y < 3 else True for y in x])
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use direct comparison or [`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ge.html) as:

```
df['B'] = df['B']>=3
```

OR

```
df['B'] = df['B'].ge(3)
```

---

```
print(df)

     A      B    C
0  0.0   True  0.0
1  0.0   True  0.0
2  0.0   True  0.0
3  0.0  False  0.0
4  0.0  False  0.0
5  0.0   True  0.0
6  6.0  False  0.0
7  0.0  False  0.0
8  0.0  False  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

simply as:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns=["data"])
>>> df["B"] = df["data"] > 2
>>> df
   data      B
0     1  False
1     2  False
2     3   True
3     4   True
>>>
```

You can even include numpy for conditional comparison like below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], columns=["A"])
>>> df["B"] = np.where(df["A"] <2, "False", "True")
>>> df
   A      B
0  1  False
1  2   True
2  3   True
3  4   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code may help your approach, when apply method get used in column then it gets all the values of that column so i don't think to use for loop here

```
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: True if x>3 else False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df.B > 3, 'new'] = True
df.loc[df.B < 3,'new'] = False
df = df.drop("B", axis=1)
df = df.rename(columns={"new": "B"})
```